# Дженерики, метод of

Tags: java, generics, optional

Почему две данных реализации работают? В чем их принципиальное отличие?

По реализации №1 - возвращается экземпляр класса Pair с переменными переданными методу of

По реализации №2 создается новый экземпляр класса Pair и двум полям класса присваиваются значения объектов и потом возвращается созданный экземпляр класса.

*правильно ли я это понимаю?*

Реализация №1:

```
public static <T, M> Pair<T, M> of(T first, M second) {
    return new Pair<>(first, second);
}
```

Реализация №2:

```
static Pair of(Object a, Object b) {
    Pair pair = new Pair();
    pair.t1 = a;
    pair.t2 = b;
    return pair;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

По реализации первой возвращается(и передается в качестве параметра) объект Pair(с дженериками), для которого были указаны все дженерики в качестве параметров конструктора. Например:

```
Pair test = new Pair<>(new Object()/*явно указали тип T!*/, new String("2")/*явно указали тип Y!*/); 
...
class Pair<T, Y>{
    T Te;
    Y Ye;
    Pair(T Te, Y Ye){
        this.Te = Te;
        this.Ye = Ye;
    }
}
```

Во второй же реализации это обычный объект Pair(без дженериков). Например:

```
Pair test = new Pair(new Object(), new Object()); 
...
class Pair{
    Object Te;
    Object Ye;
    Pair(Object Te, Object Ye){
        this.Te = Te;
        this.Ye = Ye;
    }
}
```

Если что непонятно, спрашивайте.

Comment: Pair<Integer, String> pair = Pair.of(1, "hello"); сработает как с первой реализацией так и со второй, при условии наличия класса Pair <T><M>

Comment: Ну, да, этот код сработает(Если метод of находится в классе Pair). Что вы хотите сказать?

Comment: Я хотел узнать правильны ли обе реализации и верны ли для использования?

Comment: Да, они правильны и верны. А использовать или не использовать дженерики в каком-то случае - это уже другой вопрос. Правда, я бы создал конструктор вместо метода of.

Comment: В том то и дело что я использовал дженерики и обе реализации работали одинаково. Вот в чем вопрос - корректно ли это.

Comment: В рантайме дженерики стираются всё равно, поэтому работать это в итоге будет одинаково. Дженерики в данном случае нужны для вашего блага - чтобы не выстрелить себе в ногу, передав в параметры в каком-то далёком месте кода какой-то другой тип.

Comment: @iksuy В точку. Ошибка на этапе компиляции вместо ошибки в рантайме

Comment: Спасибо Вам большое за ответы.